# Finite dimensionality of some subspace of convolution Banach algebra $L^1(G)$

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact group (not only compact group)  with the left Haar measure $\lambda$. Consider the convolution Banach algebra $L^1(G,\lambda)$. For which $f\in L^1(G,\lambda)$ the subspace $\{f*g*f: g\in L^1(G,\lambda)\}$ is not finite dimensional? For which one it is finite dimensional?

Convolution $*$:
$$\psi *\phi(x)=\int_G\psi(y)\phi(y^{-1}x)d\lambda(y)\qquad (x\in G, \psi,\phi\in L^1(G,\lambda))$$

Comment: If $G$ is a locally compact _abelian_ group then your space has finite dimension if and only if $\hat f(\xi)=0$ except for finitely many values of $\xi$ (and then if $G$ is not compact, so $\hat G$ is not discrete, this happens if and only if $f=0$). I imagine something similar holds in the non-abelian case, I don't really know anything about that.